# Who will receive the response from server if calling thread is not active?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I created ten threads who will request the server separately. Now, Each thread is requesting the server successfully but no thread is getting the response.

**If the thread is not in active state (due to Operating System Process Scheduling), who will receive the response?**

```
private static void ThreadFunc()
    {
var response = CallServer();
Console.writeline(response.Message);
}
```

Following line of code never hit.

```
Console.writeline(response.Message);
```

Comment: is this a console application?  show more of your code, such as the creation of the threads and what happens after

Comment: If the `Console.writeline(response.Message);` never hit, it mean only one thing that `CallServer()` never return. Or your process terminated before it.

Comment: Since the 'Operating System Process Scheduling' exists to manage I/O, it's much, much, much more likely that this problem is due to your client code bugs than any OS scheduling/dispatching artifacts.

Comment: There is no issue at server side, I am seeing logs at server. Server is sending response correctly. Problem is at calling side.

Comment: @operation I'm sure you're right - the problem is bugs in your client code, (or data/protocol).  What is 'CallServer' doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When waiting for a response, your thread will *never* be active. It is waiting after all.

The OS marks the underlying IO as completed and marks the thread as ready. It will be scheduled some time in the future to process the results of the completed IO.

What does "active" even mean? For the purposes of this discussion, threads can be blocked, ready and running. During a wait or IO, a thread is blocked. When that wait completes, it is marked ready. It starts to run at some point in time later when the OS decides to schedule it.

Comment: You mean on getting response, OS will mark that corresponding thread to active?

Comment: What does "active" even mean? For the purposes of this discussion, threads can be blocked, ready and running. During a wait or IO, a thread is blocked. When that wait completes, it is marked ready. It starts to run at some point in time later when the OS decides to schedule it.

Comment: By "Active", I means "in running form".

Comment: usr is right.  Your client threads will be blocked until data is received, at which point they will become ready.  If your box is not overloaded, the OS will dispatch the ready thread onto a core pretty well 'immediately' and it will run and handle the data.

Comment: @operation ok. Is your question resolved? It should be according to my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

A foreground/application thread must stay alive for background threads to completed.  If, in your code, you're using `ThreadPool` threads (which `Task`s use by default), and your console application's main thread completes without waiting for these background threads to completed, the process terminates.

Here's an example using `Task`s:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        {
            tasks.Add( Task.Factory.StartNew( () => ThreadFunc() ) );
        }

        // need this to keep process alive
        // will continue once all tasks complete
        Task.WaitAll( tasks.ToArray() );
    }
```